# How to structure this dataset for multinomial logistic regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset, logistic-regression

[image: Dataset]

I have a dataset like the one in the picture.
I need to apply Logistic Regression to this dataset and try to predict the correct result of R.
The problem is that R can assume 3 different values, as you can see in the picture (W,L,D). How can i structure it to work with logistic regression?
I am using python and sklearn logistic regression.

Comment: What have you tried so far based on your own research, and what was the result? I would start with the LabelEncoder documentation in sklearn and go from there

Comment: Please don't share information as images. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/11301900.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dataframe or numpy ndarray with A,M,D,H, lets say it as x_train and then R into another ndarrary lets name it as y_train, now you can use below

```py
LogisticRegression(multi_class='multinomial',solver ='newton-cg').fit(x_train,y_train)
```

But based on actual you may need to do some standardization/transform before you fit into a model, you can also refer to [this](https://chrisalbon.com/machine_learning/naive_bayes/multinomial_logistic_regression/) explanation on using iris data set.